# Is there any analyzer for Clang scan-build reports, similar to Jenkins xUnit plugin?

Tags: jenkins, clang, jenkins-plugins, static-analysis, scan-build

I am participating in a project that goes for more than a year. Recently our management has decided to employ routine checking of the code with the Clang static analyzer.

Our project has a CI server, based on Jenkins. Call to scan-build is added to the build script, that is started by Gitlab after push event. All build results are published in Jenkins.

Clang scan-build reports over 600 warnings. We would like to stay with them and fix eventually, but immediately fix all new problems once they appear.

I am looking for a tool or a Jenkins plugin, that would compare two reports and highlight differences, like xUnit plugin does. This plugin tracks each failed test case, shows failure age and for each build shows how many failures have been fixed / new one appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ready solution. Simplest way is to add custom parser to [Warnings plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but have you looked at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clang+Scan-Build+Plugin ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Currently use it. It cannot do it.